I can't expand one disk Minio pool with with another single disk pool
I started to work with Minio and I'm doing little POC. I have a problem with simple expanding of exiting pool. I have a pool with one server and one disk. I want to expand my tenant with new pool with 1 server with 1 disk. I do it with GUI with Pools -> Expand Tenant and I'm getting error :
ERROR Unable to initialize backend: /export/data drive is already being used in another erasure deployment. (Number of drives specified: 2 but the number of drives found in the 1st drive's format.json: 1)

I'm working with K8s operator in version: quay.io/minio/operator:v5.0.11
pool-main is exiting pools, and I want to add pool-1
My tenant config:
spec:
  buckets:
  - name: os-snapshots
  - name: backups
  configuration:
    name: minio-creds-operator
  features:
    bucketDNS: false
    enableSFTP: false
  image: quay.io/minio/minio:RELEASE.2023-11-15T20-43-25Z
  imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
  imagePullSecret: {}
  mountPath: /export
  podManagementPolicy: Parallel
  pools:
  - name: pool-main
    resources: {}
    servers: 1
    volumeClaimTemplate:
      metadata:
        name: data
      spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: 20Gi
        storageClassName: default
      status: {}
    volumesPerServer: 1
  - affinity:
      podAntiAffinity:
        requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
        - labelSelector:
            matchExpressions:
            - key: v1.min.io/tenant
              operator: In
              values:
              - minio
            - key: v1.min.io/pool
              operator: In
              values:
              - pool-1
          topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
    name: pool-1
    resources: {}
    runtimeClassName: ""
    servers: 1
    volumeClaimTemplate:
      metadata:
        name: data
      spec:
        accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
        resources:
          requests:
            storage: "21474836480"
        storageClassName: managed-csi-xfs
      status: {}
    volumesPerServer: 1
  prometheusOperator: false
  requestAutoCert: false
  subPath: /data

I want to expand exiting pool.
